# Can I accomplish this in Varnish?

Tags: caching, nginx, varnish, esi

I have a website that fetches news articles via RSS feeds from many different sites. The script adds those articles to a mysql db. I display 10 articles per page over many many pages to the viewers.

Currently I am caching full pages and purging the cache every time the update script adds new articles to the database. It's fast but not very efficient. Pages cached only have a lifespan of a few minutes, even though the articles themselves can be cached for a longer time.

Can I use varnish to store the individual articles on cache? So every page generated would have links/pointers/references to the articles, instead of having the articles themselves in there. I can then cache those pages for a short period of time while caching the articles for much longer.

How would I go about doing this on Varnish or any other caching mechanism? Would that perform worse/same as full page caches on cache hit?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and nginx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [edge side includes](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/esi.html). Basically, your pages use ESI links like this:

```
<div class="articles">
  <esi:include src="/path/to/article/1"/>
  <esi:include src="/path/to/article/2"/>
  <esi:include src="/path/to/article/3"/>
</div>
```

Now in Varnish, have this:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
  set beresp.do_esi = true;
}
```

or in Varnish 4:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
  set beresp.do_esi = true;
}
```

When the above code goes through Varnish, Varnish will replace each `esi:include` with the contents of the URL `/path/to/article/1`. You can cache the page itself for a few minutes, and each article for days.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!

"/path/to/article/1" would be something like "get-article.php?id=1" and that would be fine right? Varnish won't be hitting that file if it's already in cache I assume.

Having a dozen of those ESIs per page wouldn't be significantly slower than loading a cached page with the articles already in it?

Comment: Correct, that url is fine. Varnish doesn't parallelize requests, so each ESI include adds a small amount of loading time to uncached pages, depending on your backend (probably only a few ms). However, if you cache those pages it's not a big deal.

Comment: Thank you so much! Going to add Varnish now and will benchmark it against fastcgi-cache.